# Почему не работает сохранение фото на сервере Telegram Bot Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Мне надо сделать телеграм бота на python написал весь код но он почему-то не работает

```
file_photo = bot.get_file(user.photo_id)
filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_photo.file_path)
downloaded_file_photo = bot.download_file(file_photo.file_path)

src = 'photos/' + user.photo_id + file_extension
with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
    new_file.write(downloaded_file_photo)
```

Помогите разобраться может что то надо подправить
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: добавьте трейс ошибок, "он почему-то не работает" тут не работает ))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Путь где я выполняю код вот такой: /project/telegram/main.py
Надо просто указать такой путь ../photos/ тогда все заработает